# How do I center a character in a box using CSS?

Tags: css, centering, typography

In other words, how do I **ignore a character's depth and ascent** in instead **center it vertically** in a surrounding box based just on its bounding box?

Here is a minimal html example:

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  line-height: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<span class="box">?</span>
<span class="box">,</span>
<span class="box">`</span>
```

It produces the following:

[image: non-centered characters]

**How do I change it to produce the following instead?**

[image: centered characters]

CSS solutions are preferred if they exist, but Javascript is acceptable as a last resort. I'm looking for a general solution, not just for the three characters pictured. There will be many such boxes in my page, so performance (if Javascript is used) is important.

To clarify things even further, here is how I would do this in LaTeX:

```
\newlength{\desiredboxsize}
\setlength{\desiredboxsize}{1em}
\newcommand*{\centercharinbox}[1]{%
  % Force width
  \makebox[\desiredboxsize]{%
    % Force height and center vertically
    \raisebox{\dimexpr .5\desiredboxsize - .5\height \relax}[\desiredboxsize][0pt]{%
      % Cancel depth
      \raisebox{\depth}{#1}}}}
```

Comment: @Oriol, thanks for the edit!

Comment: I was wondering if [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.measureText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText) could be used to achieve this with JS, but it seems that vertical properties are only supported on Chrome and there they return the same value for all characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that with modern CSS. Neither can you do that out of the box with JavaScript in browsers.

Essentially: you need to get glyph outlines as paths from fonts. Using that information you can get path outline box and render / align in the way you need.

For getting glyph outlines check this [How do I get glyph outlines of a letter as bézier paths using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359711/how-do-i-get-glyph-outlines-of-a-letter-as-b%C3%A9zier-paths-using-javascript) answer for example.

Having glyph outline paths you can render them into `<canvas>` elements.

Comment: Thanks, this is a neat suggestion. I think one can push it further and build the corresponding font statically, in fact.

Comment: @Clément Yes, if it is just about one font then you can convert it to SVG images (statically). Depends on your use case.

Comment: I was thinking of just building a custom TTF, actually; fontforge has pretty good scripting support for this.

Answer (score 7):

In theory, you can do it by aligning **every** symbol individually.

Practically, you can't as every symbol has its **own depth and ascent** in the character map, especially using only CSS.

Comment: Are you sure `Character Map` is the right word here? I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean that characters were painted (made) with their position. For example: `,`, the comma is in the bottom.

Comment: Sure, that's called the ascent, descent, and depth of the `,` character IIUC. I was just suggesting to remove the mention of the character map, which seems to be an unrelated concept :) Welcome to the site, by the way!

Comment: Thanks! I've edited it to make it more easier to understand.